# Understanding UPDATE with CASE statement in ORACLE evaluating all rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to understand the results of a query I wrote in Toad for Oracle 12.1.

My test table contains 3 columns as so:

```
EMPID   LOGGEDIN   CURRENT_MONITOR
00001          1                 1
00002          1
00003          1
00004          2
```

The following SQL will update the table so that the value in  CURRENT_MONITOR is swapped from one user to another (in this case from '00001' to '00003'):

```
UPDATE CLOSED_AREA_ACCESS
SET CURRENT_MONITOR = 
CASE
  WHEN EMPID = '00001' THEN NULL
  WHEN EMPID = '00003' THEN 1
END
WHERE LOGGEDIN = 1;
```

When I run this, Toad returns the message stating that 3 rows were updated. I understand that there are 3 matching records were LOGGEDIN is 1, but I guess I'm confused as to why Toad does not state 2 records were updated. Is this because it needs to iterate through the results returned from the WHERE clause to perform the update? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Updates apply to all rows returned by the where clause. You have 3 empid rows, so all of them will be updated (empid = '00002' will have a current_monitor set to the else value of the case expression (which, in this case, would be the default, NULL, since your case expression doesn't have an else clause). If that's not what you intended, you need to update your where clause accordingly.

Comment: I didn't want anything done to the second row, so the default of NULL is correct. Do you think it would be wise to add the clause anyway?

Comment: I do, because updating 3 rows is more work than updating 2. Why do work when you don’t have to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add logic to your `WHERE` clause which also restricts the values of the `EMPID`:

```
UPDATE CLOSED_AREA_ACCESS
SET CURRENT_MONITOR = 
CASE
    WHEN EMPID = '00001' THEN NULL
    WHEN EMPID = '00003' THEN 1
END
WHERE
    LOGGEDIN = 1 AND
    EMPID IN ('00001', '00003');
```

Another approach would be to add an `ELSE` condition to the `CASE` expression which effectively no-ops and just reassigns the `CURRENT_MONITOR` to itself:

```
UPDATE CLOSED_AREA_ACCESS
SET CURRENT_MONITOR = 
CASE
    WHEN EMPID = '00001' THEN NULL
    WHEN EMPID = '00003' THEN 1
    ELSE CURRENT_MONITOR
END
WHERE LOGGEDIN = 1;
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I didn't think about using the additional logic for `IN` with the `WHERE` clause. The table above is just a test as the actual table will have more records - my concern was making sure the query was as efficient as possible.